# How to write types for a generic TypeScript function that creates a subset of an object using a list of keys as parameter?

Tags: typescript

I have a large object of key-values pairs (let's call it a "schema") that we can consider both fixed and not known in advance (it is auto-generated and can be changed in the future).

I'm trying to write a TypeScript function that allows me to do the following:

1. Declare the keys which I want to use from that schema, **and have auto-completion working when typing these keys**.
2. Generate a sub-schema with these keys and values from the original schema, and that sub-schema **must have its keys type limited to its own keys only**.

So far I can achieve either (1) or (2), but not both at the same time.

Here's my approach that solves (1):

```
// This is the original schema
const schema = {
  key1: 'value1',
  key2: 'value2',
  keyX: 'valueX',
  keyY: 'valueY'
};

const makeSubSchema = <Schema extends { [key: string]: string }, Keys extends (keyof Schema)[]>(
  base: Schema,
  keys: Keys
) => {
  // This is where I assume the problem is – as Keys[number] type is not narrowed
  // to only exactly Keys themselves
  type SubSchema = Pick<Schema, Keys[number]>;

  const subSchema = keys.reduce<SubSchema>((acc, key) => {
    acc[key] = base[key];
    return acc;
  }, {} as SubSchema);

  return subSchema;
};

// ValidKey type is generated automatically off the schema type,
// so that we can use to strictly type our keys
type ValidKey = keyof typeof schema;

// Keys are declared as type ValidKey[] so we can get auto-completion when entering
// values in the array
const mykeys: ValidKey[] = ['keyX', 'keyY'];

const myschema = makeSubSchema(schema, mykeys);

// myschema.keyX is ok - it's included into mykeys array
console.log('keyX', myschema.keyX);
// but myschema.key1 must raise a compilation error - as key1 is not included
// into mykeys. But it doesn't at the moment :(
console.log('key1', myschema.key1);
```

[this code in Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBUAsEsGdTqALpApqA9gJ2gc2gHYCGANqLAMZoC2RAUBRgbEuVaraALygDedoUAGtUATwCMALlAByAG6kArqnEyANAOFiATNPlLU29ZpGiAGnoUllZ44NMBNSwYcy6AXwDcdBkxahaEQBlRQAjIPZOHgAeCJoiUFQADyRUAgATeF5QAG1TaRYcAlwAXQKkItxQdzVQAGkxeGTUjPgAClMMADNQOI4iAEockoA+Ns1QolhUaT7aDXtG6QbRWDoB7hG+TRAIGHhEAHc0LHQASVAp2EVqdBR0AAcsDFCSDgR4QGQCAAKp+sacgQbqFUFgSshRA90IgCBhWMQsM9Dqh0sgMJgCCRRIkkkQKEgsTswFZlPBuv9VpokJD0CFwpEEjwAArQChCWIM2orWCA4Gg0beTSMZisa70+LcLSrAB0p3SigoqFiYTmRDGbTxFFqpg2XC2-EEgk1eTE4J4k2mJtEJW8htApyQiiwBEuFAotuqtV47ku8DpqoGgsEDqdLrFqu8Xh8uwAaqRoOkVhCoR9QLg0qCiEhCFUiIokBhaNmKKQsZguj17mwJdSoRpdrB0Sgs6BkaASy7FNM0eQKqyCdja+gME6pWsh6A4yQE0meJ1KzTyZR4oLdtzLqdQOlUBQSEQ5b7k+gpzOxMNyOi2x206hWHmCwBaRjUB5vbNMVtoF1pVKVOi7ElUAOF0q33LAiFEXwRQCURTFgaQT0TM8zVyGRTFsWo0LEVwbR8YV-GoVYGUlQJUH9Bk2mXfpakIuDA2jMBCKo2hpXQ1MMCEUAHwQJAZGA3dFG3VFCALGC4I3cDIPwjA3mlEgMFwNosPMdQYOYohWLEMx6N2UJ8zUhlNIkAIu1YcC4HQBJnweaA93fb9EWwLjD1McRU1hVhCAEoT-zAET0VoxppVAAAhfToFYdIMCAggZDvVgq2oQsf1ASRxmk2T5MU5TVBooj4iM8R6KAA)

As comments are saying, the problem here is that `myschema.key1` access doesn't raise an error - all keys from the original schema are considered to be valid.

I can solve this by declaring `mykeys` as a const:

```js
const mykeys = ['keyX', 'keyY'] as const;
```

[playground for this version](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBUAsEsGdTqALpApqA9gJ2gc2gHYCGANqLAMZoC2RAUBRgbEuVaraALygDedoUAGtUATwCMALlAByAG6kArqnEyANAOFiATNPlLU29ZpGiAGnoUllZ44NMBNSwYcy6AXwDcdBkxahaEQBlRQAjIPZOHgAeTQiaIlBUAA8kVAIAE3heUABtU2kWHAJcAF1CpGLcUHcNQQBpMXgUtMz4LFQiDKYSUVAAClMMADNQeI4iAEpc0roAPn7NUKJYVGlx2jqtUVhpRp26Se45vk0QCBh4RAB3NA7QAElQFdhFanQUdAAHLAxQkg4CHggGQCAAFK1A+1guQIb1CqCwpWQoi+6EQBAwrGIWF+11QGWQGEwBF6SWSRAoSF6ZzAVmU8BGkKamiQKPQIXCkUSPAACtAKEJohsiGomTsYXCEaU5t5NIxmKxXpyEtxtrAAHQdDKKCioIVhYULfoUiii0xHLgnfiCQQm-JiJE8Zare2iUreG2gDpIRRYAjPCgUD01UW8dzPeAc4WTWWCb2+-1K4XeLw+c5Q573DKoCgkIhaiPI1GgABqpGgGX2M3IRLxoAoRH9uFQrCIiiQGAAtIxqF8AUhoExQLd0kkCGkqnRznTUFd-Z9M1giKJfAqAqJTPAeLkZKZbKLd2JXEiIfKWLKz6xqDsuarAqgo1z+pQEqLr5uY2mwNeXxN1XugUwIRQE7BAkBkOdc0UbMCUIDt103Rdl1XWAMABdUSAwXB+kPcx1HXX9aH-MQzE-c5QnbAiuWIiQAkUfwlzgdBEh7L5oDzAchwRX4sBAwtTHEQCMVYQgoJgqcwDgol3yadVQAAIUo6BWG6WcCBkVtWAXagMHecdQEkRYzzQ1AMKwnCBPwn9qIEz8gA)

and this correctly raises an error at `myschema.key1` access - but I'm losing auto-completion when declaring `mykeys` values :(

It seems that the version version is closer to the correct solution, but I'm missing a way to narrow `SubSchema` type to only have exactly Keys in it.

Does anyone have any suggestions or pointers regarding how this may be solved with TypeScript?

Comment: your code appears to run fine. I see this compilation error
`Property 'key1' does not exist on type 'Pick<{ key1: string; key2: string; keyX: string; keyY: string; }, "keyX" | "keyY">'.(2339)`

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/DhLaO2WnrSS5.png

Comment: Hi @DamianGreen  
  
Thank you for taking time to look at this. I think you're looking at the second version of the code above – and it does show an error, but it has another problem - it loses auto-completion at line 30 where `mykeys` array is defined: `const mykeys = ['keyX', 'keyY'] as const;`


That's what I'm trying to solve – to have BOTH auto-completion/type-safety here when defining that array (works in the first version above), AND have `myschema.key1` access erroring (works in the second version). So far I've only been able to achieve one or the other, but not both.

Comment: What's the rationale behind needing intellisense on `myKeys` exactly? It will still be strongly typed if you declare `myKeys` as a const assertion and make the first argument readonly, e.g. shorturl.at/cpFHV. Otherwise it sounds like you're aiming for this variable to have 2 types  at the same time; the wider `ValidKey[]` and `['keyX', 'keyY'] as const`

Comment: @DamianGreen the real schema will contain hundreds of keys, so defining `myKeys` without intellisense/autocompletion will be very tedious and time consuming to get it right. To maybe rephrase what I'm trying to achieve – I don't want `myKeys` to be typed as const, it was just one of my approaches here. What I want is `myschema` as a return value of `makeSubSchema` function to be narrowed from `keyof Schema` to only precisely the values of its `keys` parameter.